# Как прописать условия для группы данных?

Tags: sql-server

**Исходная таблица:**

| ID | Название | Дата | Статус |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Название1 | 01.01.2023 | Нет |
| 1 | Название2 | 05.04.2023 | Нет |
| 1 | Название3 | 12.08.2023 | Да |
| 2 | Название1 | 05.07.2023 | Нет |
| 2 | Название2 | 12.05.2023 | Нет |
| 2 | Название3 | 10.12.2023 | Нет |

**Результат, который я хочу получить:**

| ID | Название | Дата | Статус |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Название1 | 05.07.2023 | Нет |

Мне необходимо получить результат по условию из первой таблицы :

1. Статус по группе (по ID) у всех должен стоять "Нет".
2. Выбрать минимальную строку с минимальной датой, если подходит под 1 пункт.

Comment: А если групп, удовлетворяющих первому условию, несколько?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала с помощью группировки и `having` выберите такие строки, где число записей равно числу строк с `Нет`, и минимальную дату  к ним. Потом заджойните к базовой таблице. Примерно так:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT id, MIN(date) AS dmin
    FROM t
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) = SUM(IF(status = 'нет', 1, 0))
)
SELECT t.*
FROM t
INNER JOIN data AS d ON (
    d.id = t.id 
    AND d.dmin = t.date
)
```

Comment: ```HAVING MIN(status) = 'Нет'``` попроще будет..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
      AND t2.status = 'Да'
    )
ORDER BY [date] ASC, id ASC;
```

Если имеется несколько `id`, для которых выполняется условие (1), будет возвращена одна запись для той группы, где дата самая наименьшая. Если таких групп несколько (минимальная дата одинакова), будет возвращена запись с минимальным `id`.